# How to start a JPanel after switching using CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, cardlayout

So i am building a game with Swing. My main game is in a JPanel called Board while the the starting screen is a JPanel called StartScreen, i also made a JPanel called MainPanel with a CardLayout layout that i use to switch between the two panels.

MainPanel:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

JPanel startMenu, board;

public MainPanel(){

    setLayout(new CardLayout());
    startMenu = new StartMenu(this);
    board = new Board();
    add(startMenu, "startMenu");
    add(board, "board");
}
}
```

My problem is that once i initialize board, the constructor of the board panel is crating and starting a thread that will run the game, so by the time i switch to the game, the game has already started running. Is there a way to start the game only when the i switch to the second panel.

Right now this is the constructor for Board:

```
public Board(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyBoard());
    snake = new Snake();
    apple = new Apple();
    thread = new Thread(Board.this);
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

These suggestions may seem simplistic, but simplistic is what you likely need:

- Don't start your game thread in the constructor.
- When you swap to the game panel, start your thread there.
- Also, you really should avoid using KeyListeners with Swing applications since it is considered a very low-level listener. Better to use Key Bindings if applicable.

e.g.,

```
public void swapToBoard() {
   cardLayout.show(mainContainer, "board");
   new Thread(boardInstance).start;
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Yes but i would start the thread outside of the constructor, when i am switching JPanel i am just making the panel visible. I was thinking of implementing a listener that gets called when the panel becomes visible .

And that is what I believe is one problem with CardLayout -- I know of no such listener for this event, and if you look at its API, you'll see no such listener. You will likely have to hard-code it into your swap method.

Comment: Yes but i would start the thread outside of the constructor, when i am switching JPanel i am just making the panel visible. I was thinking of implementing a listener that gets called when the panel becomes visible .

Comment: Thanks, yes i solved the problem by writing a function called getThread() in board and after calling CardLayout.next() i call board.getThread().start(). I'm not sure if its the cleanest solution but it works. I also considered adding a while loop that would constantly check for a boolean to be true and adding a method to board from which i can set the boolean to true. But i'm afraid it might be less efficient.

Comment: @Danielcode10 : Please have a look at this small code [StartStopPauseThread.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5021rcrhw3ewngd/StartStopPauseThread.java), you can modify this small example to your needs and then incorporate the thingy in your actual Game. I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking of implementing a listener that gets called when the panel becomes visible .

You can use a `ComponentListener` and listen for `componentShown` or you can use an `AncestorListener` and listen for `ancestorAdded`.